# Changing the value of textview in android

Tags: android

I'm new here and also in android development. I have problem in my code
I want that when I click on radio group the text of text view must be changed. but this is not happening. Can somebody help me?

Here is my code

```html
package com.example.mine4.truefalse;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DigitalClock;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class NewGame extends Activity {
    int min = 1;
    int max = 20;
    int randm = (int)(Math.random() * max) + min;
    TextView level;
    TextView clock,text;
    RadioGroup rg1;
    int pos1,pos2,AVal,j=0;
    RadioButton radio1,radio2;

    QueryClass qc = new QueryClass(this);

    int correct=0;
    int wrong=0;
    String q;
    ArrayList QVal;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_game);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textv);
        radio1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        radio2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        rg1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg1);
        qc.open();
        AVal = qc.getANSData(randm);
        QVal = qc.getQueData(randm);

            q = (String) QVal.get(j);
            text.setText(q);
             qc.close();
            rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    pos1 = rg1.indexOfChild(findViewById(checkedId));
                    pos2 = rg1.indexOfChild(findViewById(rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));

                }


            });
            rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    pos1 = rg1.indexOfChild(findViewById(checkedId));
                    pos2 = rg1.indexOfChild(findViewById(rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
                    if(pos2==AVal){
                        correct++;
                        text.setText("The fastest time to eat 15 Ferrero Rocher is 1 minute 10 seconds.");
                    }
                    else if(pos2!=AVal) {
                      text.setText("The fastest time to eat 15 Ferrero Rocher is 1 minute 10 seconds.");

                        wrong++;
                        // Toast.makeText(NewGame.this,wrong+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(NewGame.this,pos2+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Check();
                }


            });
        }



    public void Check(){
        if(pos2==AVal){
            correct++;
            //Toast.makeText(NewGame.this,correct+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(pos2!=AVal) {
            wrong++;
           // Toast.makeText(NewGame.this,wrong+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_new_game, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        // code here to show dialog
        super.onBackPressed();  // optional depending on your needs
        Intent intn = new Intent(NewGame.this,Exmain.class);
        startActivity(intn);
    }
}
```

Comment: is it really Your intent that Your random randm will allways be the same value?

Comment: you should not be register the radiogroup checkchangedlistener 2 times...this is the first mistake..i think thats why on event call...the first listener is fired..and nothing to work on textview..as that listener block doesn't contain code to do the change on textview text

Comment: sir check the new code which i uploaded in this session
but it is also not working

Answer (score 0):

i have changed your code .. now check

```
package com.example.mine4.truefalse;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DigitalClock;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class NewGame extends Activity {
    int min = 1;
    int max = 20;
    int randm = (int)(Math.random() * max) + min;
    TextView level;
    Button b1;
    TextView text;
    RadioGroup rg1;
    int pos1=0,pos2,AVal,j=0;
    RadioButton radio1,radio2;
    QueryClass qc = new QueryClass(this);

    int correct=0;
    int wrong=0;
    String q;
    ArrayList QVal;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_game);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textv);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
//        radio1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
//        radio2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
//        rg1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg1);
        qc.open();
        AVal = qc.getANSData(randm);
        QVal = qc.getQueData(randm);

            q = (String) QVal.get(j);
            text.setText(q);
             qc.close();
            b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    for(j=0;j<QVal.size();j++) {
                        if(pos1<9) {
                            text.setText((String) QVal.get(j));
                            pos1++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
                }
    public void Check(){
        if(pos2==AVal){
            correct++;
            //Toast.makeText(NewGame.this,correct+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(pos2!=AVal) {
            wrong++;
           // Toast.makeText(NewGame.this,wrong+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_new_game, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        // code here to show dialog
        super.onBackPressed();  // optional depending on your needs
        Intent intn = new Intent(NewGame.this,Exmain.class);
        startActivity(intn);
    }
}
```

Comment: sir I used your suggestions but i am not getting my result
i am uploading the new changes which i think are better

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
RadioGroup rg1=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg1);

    rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) 
        {
            if(radio1.isChecked())
            {
                   text.setText("The fastest time to eat 15 Ferrero Rocher is 1 minute 10 seconds.");  //or what you want to stay inyour textView
            }
            else if(radio2.isChecked())
            {
                   text.setText("The fastest time to eat 15 Ferrero Rocher is 1 minute 10 seconds."); //or what you want to stay inyour textView
            }
         }
    });
```

instead of this part of your code:

```
rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pos1 = rg1.indexOfChild(findViewById(checkedId));
                pos2 = rg1.indexOfChild(findViewById(rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));

            }


        });
        rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pos1 = rg1.indexOfChild(findViewById(checkedId));
                pos2 = rg1.indexOfChild(findViewById(rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
                if(pos2==AVal){
                    correct++;
                    text.setText("The fastest time to eat 15 Ferrero Rocher is 1 minute 10 seconds.");
                }
                else if(pos2!=AVal) {
                  text.setText("The fastest time to eat 15 Ferrero Rocher is 1 minute 10 seconds.");

                    wrong++;
                    // Toast.makeText(NewGame.this,wrong+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                Toast.makeText(NewGame.this,pos2+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Check();
            }


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
RadioGroup rg1;
TextView text;
text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textv);
rg1= (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg1);



    rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {



        @Override

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            // find which radio button is selected

            if(checkedId == R.id.radio1) {
              text.setText("Radio 1 selected");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Radio 1 selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if(checkedId == R.id.radio2) {

                text.setText("Radio 2 selected");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Radio 2 selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {

                //do something when nothing selected

            }

        }



    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is new code please check it out

```html
package com.example.mine4.truefalse;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DigitalClock;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class NewGame extends Activity {
    int min = 1;
    int max = 20;
    int randm = (int)(Math.random() * max) + min;
    TextView level;
    TextView clock,text;
    RadioGroup rg1;
    int pos1,pos2,AVal,j=0,k=0;
    RadioButton radio1,radio2;
    QueryClass qc = new QueryClass(this);

    int correct=0;
    int wrong=0;
    String q;
    ArrayList QVal;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_game);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textv);
        radio1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        radio2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        rg1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg1);
        qc.open();
        AVal = qc.getANSData(randm);
        QVal = qc.getQueData(randm);

        q = (String) QVal.get(j);
        text.setText((String) QVal.get(j));
        qc.close();
        rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for(j=0;j<QVal.size();j++) {
                    if(k<9) {
                        text.setText((String) QVal.get(j));
                        pos1 = rg1.indexOfChild(findViewById(checkedId));
                        pos2 = rg1.indexOfChild(findViewById(rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
                        Check();
                        k++;
                    }
                }
            }


        });

    }



    public void Check(){
        if(pos2==AVal){
            correct++;
            //Toast.makeText(NewGame.this,correct+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(pos2!=AVal) {
            wrong++;
            // Toast.makeText(NewGame.this,wrong+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_new_game, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        // code here to show dialog
        super.onBackPressed();  // optional depending on your needs
        Intent intn = new Intent(NewGame.this,Exmain.class);
        startActivity(intn);
    }
}
```